# Ubuntu Server 20.04 not booting up

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my old PC, and it fails booting up every time.
I'm using a USB as an installation media, and after removing the USB from the PC, it fails to boot up Ubuntu.
tried installing boot-repair on the installation media's terminal, failed. After that, installed boot-repair on my USB, booted up, ran 'Recommended Repair", got the URL, but eventually failed when I tried to boot it up after removing the USB.

URL: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZJSRNVJ2Xw/

Windows is not installed on the PC, I'm trying to use Ubuntu Server as my only operating system.

Edit:
Additional information:
used 'ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso' to install Ubuntu Server,
used a brand new SSD for the PC, so no previous partitions,
used 'boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso' for Boot Repair,

PC Specs: i5-4670(3.40GHz, 4 cores), 8G RAM, GTX 760, so it satisfies the minimum requirements.

Edit2:
I have checked with SHA256SUM, there was nothing wrong with the .iso file.
I have also tried changing boot options, but the problem wasn't solved. (but I'm not too sure if I did it correctly...)

(Probably) Final Edit: 
I tried installing Ubuntu Server with UEFI mode, and it booted up successfully. Thanks to everyone who helped me with this problem.

Comment: You said old PC does it meet the hardware requirements of Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Some details on exactly how it fails would be really helpful. Error messages, for example.

Comment: **Please edit your original question to answer the following:** Which iso file did you use to install Ubuntu Server (name of the file)? Did you check with sha256sum that is was successfully downloaded? Did you remove all previous partitions from the target drive (the internal drive of the computer) before starting the installer? Which iso file did you use to run Boot Repair? What computer is it (brand name and model)? - The answers can help us help you. (We may need some more information later on, and there may be some trial and error, but I think that you will succeed.)

Comment: does it boot into grub?

Comment: I think there can be a problem with the graphics card. The [first] workaround is to boot with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. It might be enough. Maybe you should also activate `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2).